# Signalling a root C++ executabke from a non-privileged Java Android app

Tags: android, android-source, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I am amending an Android C++ system executable (healthd), which runs as root.

I want the amended healthd to be able to receive some form of signal from an unprivileged Android Java app.

A few hundred ms of latency is fine, as is polling from healthd, rather than an actual "event".

I only need to send an indication that something has happened - there's no requirement to transport data.

What's the simplest form of communication I can use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can my Android app communicate with a native daemon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899413/how-can-my-android-app-communicate-with-a-native-daemon)

Comment: Another resource: https://devarea.com/aosp-adding-a-native-daemon/

Comment: @RickSanchez Thanks - Can a non-system app use `LocalSocketAddress()`?  Assuming it can, this answers my question.

Comment: I don't know. Try it and report back the error if there is any. If it doesn't work you can always make a system app that exposes an API via standard broadcasts, and does the socket connection internally.